# Unknown cURL Error? resource(184, curl)

Tags: php, apache, curl, centos7

So I have this PHP code:

From another function I do:

```
$this->getCourses($Id);
```

To run this function:

```
public function getCourses($Id)
    {
      $getLogin = curl_init("https://api.litmos.com/v1.svc/users/".$Id."?apikey=API_KEY&source=MY_SOURCE&format=json");
        curl_setopt($getLogin, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        curl_setopt($getLogin, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
        curl_setopt($getLogin, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($getLogin, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($getLogin, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        $result = curl_exec($getLogin);
        return var_dump($getLogin);
        curl_close($getLogin);
    }
```

And this is the response...

```
resource(186, curl)
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, I can't put the URL because it contains our API Key...  Is there any other parts to the code that you would recommend?

Comment: The actual URL without your API key and what your "some-option" value is. Additionally, is this code inside of a function? What are you `return`ing from?

Comment: @bugfroggy - I've updated my question with more of the actual code (minus  my API key and source info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource you get, is the handle for `curl` session. For accessing the result of curl execution, you should `var_dump($result)` in your code, not `$getLogin`.

Comment: Ha!  Your right, I blame a long day of looking at code..  in rearranging things I managed to correct it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get error raised by calling `curl_exec`, try `curl_error($getLogin)` rather than `var_dump($getLogin)`

Reference: [function.curl-error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: Good suggestion Fu Xu, I tried that and there was no output.

Answer (score 0):

Huh... well I moved the cURL call into the current scope and changed the init string single quotes and added some spacing in ' . $Id . '... and now it works!?